# the workflow bulit with webpack and react.when i run 'npm run dev',there is an error:Module parse failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

> error:
>   ERROR in ./app/main.js
>   Module parse failed: E:\project\app\main.js Unexpected token (9:14)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:14)
>       at Parser.pp.raise (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:923:13)
>       at Parser.pp.unexpected (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1490:8)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:333:12)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:228:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:207:17)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:154:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:136:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:112:19)
>       at Parser.pp.parseExprList (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:660:23)
>       at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (E:\project\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:252:29)
>    @ multi main
>   文件路径：

[enter image description here][1]

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
entry: [
'webpack/hot/dev-server',
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
 path.resolve(__dirname,'app/main.js')
],
output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,'build'),
    filename:'bundle.js'
},
module :{
    loaders :[
            {
                test:/\.jsx$/,
                loader:'babel-loader',
                exclude:/node_modules/,

                query:
                    {
                        presets:['es2015','stage-0','react']
                    }
            }
    ]
}};
```

**component.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Hello extends React.Component{
render(){
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}}
```

**main.js:**

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import Hello from './component.jsx';
main();
function main(){
React.render(<Hello />,document.getElementById('app'));}
```

**package.json**

```
{
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack",
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --           content-base build"},
"dependencies": {
"react": "^15.2.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.10.4",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4"}}
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you two changes:
You should update your loader from

```
test:/\.jsx$/
```

to

```
test:/\.(js|jsx)$/
```

for your loaders with react presets to be applied on both `.js` and `.jsx` file
Also in you `main.js` use `ReactDOM.render()` instead of `React.render()`. And you don't really need to write it in a function though.

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './component.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loaders with `react` `presets` will be applied only on `.jsx` file extensions. Since you have JSX code in `main.js` file you should update your loader from

```
test:/\.jsx$/
```

to

```
test:/\.(js|jsx)$/
```

it simply says: test `.js` or `.jsx`.

Comment: I do as you suggest。But there is an error : `webpack:///./app/main.js?:18 Uncaught TypeError: _react2.default.render is not a function`